# traversing a ttk::treeview in Tk

Tags: treeview, tcl, tk-toolkit

Is there a simple way to traverse the items of a Tcl/Tk `ttk::treview` as if they were items in a listbox?  Example:

```
               A
           |   |-- B
    visit  |   |   |-- C
    order  |   |   |-- D         ---->    A B C D E F G
           |   E
           V   |-- F
                   |-- G
```

I understand that this would correspond to traversing the tree in preorder and this is, in fact, my current solution. Since I do have a complete tree with maximum depth N, I can do something like:

```
foreach lev1 [.tree children {}] {
    do_stuff $lev1 
    foreach lev2 [.tree children $lev1] {
        do_stuff$lev2
        foreach lev3 [.tree children $lev2] {
            do_stuff $lev3
               ....
        }
    }
}
```

but I am looking for an easier way to do it.

I have considered adding a tag (say `mytag`) to each node and use: `.tree tag has mytag` to get the list of all the nodes. The problem is that,  AFAIK, the resulting order is not guaranteed and I may end up with a different type of visit.

Answer (score 3):

Recursive traversal ought to do the trick for you. Something along the lines of

```
proc traverse {item} {
    do_stuff $item
    foreach [.tree children $item] {
        traverse $item
    }
}


.tree traverse {}
```

Feels fairly simple too.

(Disclaimer: I haven't actually tested this.)

Comment: thanks @nurdglaw. Yes, it would solve the traversal and it's basically what I'm doing, except that my tree has a known depth and, thus, I'm able to sort-of "unroll the recursion". I was hoping I could leverage the fact that the widget already has the elements in the order that I need and it would be much simpler if there was a widget function to traverse the tree in that order.

Comment: I guess it would be easier if there were some widget function to return all the items in order, but there isn't one. For my money, your "unrolling the recursion" is making the code less simple, but I guess it's a matter of taste. If you need to do this type of traversal in lots of places, you could wrap the ttk::notebook in your own class and add a member function to return all the items, then iterate down the list it returns "doing_stuff".

Comment: @Remo.D If you were using 8.6, it would be internally “unrolling the recursion” for you. But for any sane depth of tree, it shouldn't matter. After all, “try the simplest thing that could possibly work” is a classic principle of software engineering.